# writing iterable variable from a loop into a python list

Tags: python, list

Several questions related to the same issue have been posted, but do not find a solution  to my problem. I would like to get the output of my loop (list of 2000 floats) into a python list. I am getting the "variable non iterable error" because I am not managing to call each of the elements of the output in the right way to be written into a list.

Other attempts, like converting to a list inside the loop, give me a list per element, when I need only one list with all the elements inside.

This is my code:

```
for i in range(x):
    timedelta= (function(i)) #datetime.timedelta elements 
    pos_time = (i, function(i)) #tuple of an integer and a float
    time = pos_time[1]
    print time
```

If I finish here I get the list of values I need:

```
3.5
2.04
6.6
4.02
...
```

If I continue inside the loop:

```
times = []
for time in range(x):
    times.append(time)
```

then I get a list from consecutive values, not really the output from the loop.
What I need is a list like:

```
times = [3.5,2.04,6.6,4.02]
```

I would appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 2):

On your second attempt ("If I continue inside the loop"), you were very close, just add the function call:

```
times = []
for time in range(x):
    times.append(function(time))
```

Also, you might want to look at the [*map()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) function to build the list of function results directly:

```
 map(function, range(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
times = [function(i) for i in range(x)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but I am afraid that does not give me what I want. I get arrays of 2000 equal elements that it is the first value of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing, append to the times list:

```
times = []
for i in range(x):
    time= (function(i)) 
    pos_time = (i, function(i))
    time = pos_time[1]
    # print time 
    times.append(time)
```

I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're trying to do inside the for-loop though:

```
time= (function(i))
```

is the same as

```
time = function(i)
```

i.e. calling `function` with the loop variable as a paramter.

```
pos_time = (i, function(i))
```

creates a tuple of `i` the loop variable and a second call to `function(i)`.

```
time = pos_time[1]
```

then gets the second/last value of the tuple you created.

If `function(i)` returns the same value every time you call it with `i`, you could simply do

```
times = []
for i in range(x):
    time = function(i)
    times.append(time)
```